# Messed up my pip and python installs

Tags: python, pip

Working with linux mint, I went to install a package yesterday with pip.

```
user@mycomp ~ $ pip install bitmex-ws
The program 'pip' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python-pip
```

Ok, installing pip

```
jason@speedylinux ~ $ sudo apt install python-pip
```

And it appears to complete fine. Trying again...

```
jason@speedylinux ~ $ pip install bitmex-ws
Collecting bitmex-ws
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/5c/6ea7f43b49cf46b0d1552abd6ab89aae4f74641ebca2d836c52737300ea1/bitmex-ws-0.3.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named setuptools
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Thinking it was a problem with that last error (but it looks like it was actually just that setuptools wasn't installed), just doing as it says...

```
user@mycomp ~ $ pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

I was stumped at this point and did a bunch of googling and SO searching. Ended up doing this after:

```
jason@speedylinux ~ $ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

success.

```
jason@speedylinux ~ $ python get-pip.py
/tmp/tmpM7KfNh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 18.0
    Uninstalling pip-18.0:
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/pip3'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

which seemed weird. 
so I did the ill-advised (DO NOT RUN)

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

which apparently was not a good idea. Didn't know it at the time.

That returned

```
    The directory '/home/jason/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/jason/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 4.5MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 18.0
    Uninstalling pip-18.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-18.0
Successfully installed pip-18.0
```

Now its messed up.
Not sure how to go from here. My end goal is to install that bitmex package.
Here are the results of some commands

```
jason@speedylinux ~ $ python -m pip

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.
  warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)

Usage:   
  /usr/bin/python -m pip <command> [options]

Commands:
  install                     Install packages.
  download ... etc

jason@speedylinux ~ $ pip
bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory
jason@speedylinux ~ $ which python
/usr/bin/python
jason@speedylinux ~ $ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
jason@speedylinux ~ $ which pip
/home/jason/.local/bin/pip
jason@speedylinux ~ $ pip
bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory
jason@speedylinux ~ $ pip install bitmex-ws
bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

any help much appreciated

Comment: You apparently have mixed versions of Python and installed a version of pip for python3 with python2. https://superuser.com/ should be a better place to ask

Answer (score 1):

`python-pip` is an `aptitude` installed package, as you've seen, that isn't explicitly linked to a python distribution. What I would do is uninstall your current python installation and reinstall with your preferred version.

`python get-pip.py` should only be run for versions that don't have `pip` natively installed (i.e., not python 3.x). If you are running python3.x, just reinstall either from a `tar.gz` or from binaries. Then, make sure that python installation is what your linux box is pointing to.

Usually when `pip-install`ing packages, you'll want `python -m pip install...` to make sure you aren't using the `apt` installed `pip`

Comment: Thats safe? I'm using linux mint, I heard some critical system functions depend on python somewhere...?

Comment: If you're using another installation of python, yes. The native build, no

Answer (score -1):

in addition, I think you should consider the following if you are on Linux

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: please write a complete answer if you want to post it as an answer. If you want to complete someone else's answer, consider adding a comment under that answer.